# I want to Automate on Active Inactive Buttons with this aria-hidden="true"

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

Want to click on Active inactive buttons on web table having following CSS

Tried with `//td[contains(text(),'100003')]/following-sibling::td/div/ul/li/a/i[@id='active']`  xpath

```
<i _ngcontent-c9="" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-icon material-icons ng-star-inserted" id="inactive" mattooltip="Activate" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-14" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">public</i>


<i _ngcontent-c9="" class="mat-icon material-icons ng-star-inserted" id="active" mat-raised-button="" mattooltip="Suspend" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-16" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">public</i>
```

Tried with `//td[contains(text(),'100003')]/following-sibling::td/div/ul/li/a/i[@id='active']`  xpath

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? What is Active Inactive button? Provide couple of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a typo, the `<i _ngcontent-c9` part of your tag might be throwing the XPath selector off. Try replacing the `i` tag with a `*`:

`//td[contains(text(),'100003')]/following-sibling::td/div/ul/li/a/*[@id='active']`

Since you haven't posted the rest of the page source, I can't verify whether or not the issue is with any other part of the path. If this solution doesn't work, please post additional page source information and any error messages you are receiving so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

As Christine points out, it is difficult to confirm any solution without additional page source, but assuming that the id 'active' is truly unique (it's supposed to be, but I've seen bad html in the past), you could just use:

```
//i[@id='active']
```